# Search between two dates columns using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, relational-database, jpql

It's saying that i cannot use the operator with this type of variable, but why?

My idea was to have two text fields, one that would receive the end date and another with the start date, passing as parameter values, and then returning a list of objects with the relatives dates

```
[59, 66] The identification variable 'endDate' cannot be used in conjunction   `with the <= operator.
[35, 44] The identification variable 'startDate' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[59, 66] The identification variable 'endDate' is not defined in the FROM clause.
```

im using jDatachosser, And that's how I get the dates

```
String startDate= ((JTextField) txtDatainicio.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String endDate= ((JTextField) txtDataFim.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And thats the method to return the list

```
 public List<Ordemservico> findDates(String date1, String date2) {


    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    TypedQuery<Ordemservico> query = em.createQuery("select u from Ordemservico u where startDate>= :date1 AND endDate <= :date2", Ordemservico.class);
    query.setParameter("date1", date1);
    query.setParameter("date2", date2);
    List<Ordemservico> layoutsSelected = query.getResultList();

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return layoutsSelected;
}
```

My classe

```
public class Ordemservico implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idordemservico")
private Integer idordemservico;
@Column(name = "identificadoros")
private Integer identificadoros;
@Column(name = "mes")
private Integer mes;
@Column(name = "ano")
private Integer ano;
@Column(name = "assunto")
private String assunto;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "publicitario")
private String publicitario;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "layoutos")
private String layoutos;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "startDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Column(name = "endDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
@Column(name = "dataevento")
```

Answer (score 1):

In JPA when you create the query you have to put the object to wich the attribute belongs to, try with:

```
TypedQuery<Ordemservico> query = em.createQuery("select u from Ordemservico u where u.startDate>= :date1 AND u.endDate <= :date2", Ordemservico.class);
```

look the condition **u.**startDate>= :date1 not just startDate>= :date1

Answer (score 0):

solution given by Dazak is correct, to refer to a property of an entity you must mention which entity as well. In addition to that, startDate and endDate of your entities are of type java.util.Date .

```
@Column(name = "startDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Column(name = "endDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
private Date endDate;
```

But you are setting the date parameters in the query as string. Instead they must of Date type.

```
findDates(String date1, String date2)
...
query.setParameter("date1", date1);//value should be of Date type
query.setParameter("date2", date2);//same as above
```

After changes, it should look like the following:

```
static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public List<Ordemservico> findDates(String date1, String date2) {
    Date parsedDate1 = sdf.parse(date1);
    Date parsedDate2 = sdf.parse(date2);
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    TypedQuery<Ordemservico> query = em.createQuery("select u from Ordemservico u where u.startDate>= :date1 AND u.endDate <= :date2", Ordemservico.class)
    query.setParameter("date1", parsedDate1);// value must be date as the property we are comparing is of Date type
    query.setParameter("date2", parsedDate2);// same as above
    List<Ordemservico> layoutsSelected = query.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return layoutsSelected;
}
```

Moreover, if you want only comparison at date level ignoring the time value, you can have a look at the following method:

```
//Class: TypedQuery
setParameter(String name, Date value,TemporalType temporalType);
```